# How do I keep audiobook separate from Google Music?

Tags: google-play-music, audiobooks

So every time I add an audiobook to my Nexus7 it automatically put it into google music. And then of course if I'm listening to music I suddenly get part of a story, which is really annoying.
I tried putting .nomedia on the audiobook file but it doesn't make any differences

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Google Music will ignore the `.nomedia` hint file. But you can create a folder beginning with a "." and put there all the audio files you don't want to be indexed by Google Music.

For example:

> /sdcard/.AudioNotToShowInGMusic/

Answer (score 1):

I have a different phone, and have issues also with the media applications ignoring the .nomedia flag.
A web search indicated that the .nomedia flag is not working as expected because of a Cache.  (the previously scanned data remains in said cache)

Renaming the folder, then re-scanning the media seems to fix this issue with the cache holding the data even after the .nomedia item is present.  After scanning, the folder can then be renamed back, and additional media scans seem to properly ignore the folder.
I am not sure if this is a long term workaround, or just another bad workaround, but so far it has solutioned it for me on my device.

Update, renaming and rescanning the media has worked 100% for month now, only if a new set of items are scanned prior to the .nomedia flag being placed in it's folder, do I have to apply that method again.  So .nomedia goes on first :-) . I see many programs are tossing the flag in early , even if thier folder is empty at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Creating the .nomedia file worked for me, as did @Tzunki's additional solution of putting a "." in front of my audiobooks folder name.  However, adding that "." made the folder hidden and so i couldn't access it to add and delete new and old audiobooks on my computer. I couldn't find it on my phone or on my computer until I installed ES Explorer and checked the box to show hidden files. Then i could delete out the "." from my phone to then make the file accessible on my computer.
Thanks again to @Tzunki for the original answer and to @gertmenkel for the solution to finding the hidden file (that discussion [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/127957/i-cant-find-my-nomedia-folder-or-the-folder-it-is-in-anymore-but-the-files-st?noredirect=1#comment159231_127957))!