# I can't find my .nomedia folder or the folder it is in anymore, but the files still seem to be there

Tags: file-management, google-play-music, audiobooks

I recently followed the advice posted from [How do I keep audiobook separate from Google Music?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/37565/how-do-i-keep-audiobook-separate-from-google-music/62542#62542) by @Tzunki in order to keep my audiobooks out of Google Play Music.

I made a `.Audiobooks` folder and put them all in there and then added a `.nomedia` folder for good measure. It worked great, but now I'm trying to delete out an old audiobook and add a new one, and I can't find the folder or any of the audiobooks.

I've tried searching for the files and the folder names, etc., but it looks like they are all hidden somehow and I can't find any of them in order to edit them. I went back to my audiobook player to make sure they are still there and played them and they play. I checked the root folder for the files in my audiobook player and it shows `/storage/emulated/0/.audiobooks` (which is not where I told it to look when I created the `.Audiobooks` folder) but I looked there and there is some data file instead of the audiobooks, so I'm thinking it is just like a bookmark so it knows where in the audiobook I left off?

I've tried to just type in `Computer\Galaxy S6\Phone\.Audiobooks`, but it says Windows can't find it. Also, I thought I might try to re-create it, and see if it repopulated with my files but when I try to change the name of my `New Folder` to `.Audiobooks`, it won't change, it just reverts back to `New Folder`.

Any help you can offer would be great.

Comment: In many Unix-like operating systems, such as Android, file names starting with a . are hidden by default. If you are using a file explorer app you might need to enable "show hidden files" in its settings. Can you post what app you're using to search for your files and what app you're using to listen to your audio books?

Comment: @gertmenkel - I'm  just plugging it into my PC and searching in windows explorer.  The app i'm using to listen is [Smart Audiobook Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ak.alizandro.smartaudiobookplayer&hl=en).  I was thinking the same, but the "show hidden files" option is checked in the folder options.  any ideas?  thanks!

Comment: Have you tried renaming the .Audiobooks folder using a file explorer app on the phone? Try renaming it and then check if yoir PC can see the files again. It could be that something is protecting the folder making your PC unable to see it.

Comment: @gertmenkel Oh, sorry, forgot to mention that I can't find the .Audiobooks folder on the phone either. Using the "My Files" app - the default samsung tool thing - it doesnt show up and it can't find it if i search for it or any of the audiobook files either.

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks to [@gertmenkel](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/109702/gertmenkel). I found the hidden files using ES Explorer and deleted out the "." so that the file wasn't hidden anymore. The audiobooks are still not in my Google Play Music because of the `.nomedia` file I have in there. So the "." in the audiobooks file name was overkill.